# How to change string in cell to blank within dplyr (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe in R

```
data <- structure(list(Column = c("0 bps", "3 bps", "NA bps", "NA bps", 
"NA bps")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Is there any way in which I could change the last three cells (the strings with "NA bps" in them) to a blank cell (preferably within dplyr)?

TIA

Comment: How are you defining a 'blank' cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(Column = gsub("NA bps", "", Column))
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  Column 
  <chr>  
1 "0 bps"
2 "3 bps"
3 ""     
4 ""     
5 ""
```

Answer (score 1):

`R Base`, Try:

```
data$Column[data$Column=="NA bps"] <- NA
```

`dlpyr` Try:

```
data %>% mutate(Column =  recode(carb,"NA bps"=NA_character_))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```r
dplyr::na_if(data, "NA bps")                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                              - output

#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   Column
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 0 bps 
#> 2 3 bps 
#> 3 <NA>  
#> 4 <NA>  
#> 5 <NA>
```